# Jquery do something on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add a `.click` to this script, to jump to the next text from `wordsArray`?

```js
$(function() {
  count = 0;
  let wordsArray = ["projact management", "quality assurance", "qualitative research", "artificial reality"];
  setInterval(function() {
    count++;
    $("#What-We-Do-Text-2").slideToggle(500, function() {
      $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).slideToggle(500);
    });
  }, 15000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where do you want to put the click? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if what you want to do is only move on to the next element in the list.

Code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
      count = 0;
      let wordsArray = ["projact management", "quality assurance", "qualitative research", "artificial reality"];
      $("#What-We-Do-Text-2").text(wordsArray[count]);
    
      $("#What-We-Do-Text-2").click(function() {
        if(count < (wordsArray.length - 1)) {
          count ++;
          $("#What-We-Do-Text-2").text(wordsArray[count]);
        } else {
          count = 0;
          $("#What-We-Do-Text-2").text(wordsArray[count]);
        }
      });
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="What-We-Do-Text-2" type="button"></div>
```